# How to address a specific android phone to send push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I wanted to know how to address a specific android phone to send push notifications as the google's gcm is slow and also as i want to learn how to send push notifications without google cloud messaging and to build my own api for sending push notifications to other platform devices .

I'm not sure how to address an android phone whether by its IP address or keep a socket for listening at a port.

Please help!

Comment: This is an open ended question, but I would suggest you look into the Parse SDK. Specifically their [Push API](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android).

Answer (score 0):

You not need to use ports or some listening mechanism to build. Use the Google's GCM way.

You need to build a service that will periodically check your server for any massages to get (fetch) for your specific device (keep a self created unique id with each device and registered the device on your the server by that id). Actually this is not pushing. but this is what happening in the GCM server also. When you put some massage for some specific device to your server(it is the pushing) the device  will grab that by the service running on it.

1. simply you have to create a server by yourself (like GCM server)
2. Then you have to create a service to run on mobile to check updates on your server (like android play service)

Comment: but checking periodically for updates on the mobile is not exactly pushing. My question is how to address the phone from the server to send push notifications.

Comment: for that u need a static ip or something like that for your phone. The best way is what i have mentioned. Its not really pushing, but virtually it does, you are only need to put your msg to the server.
And this is one of the easy-possible way and also the same way GCM is working.